# No info in the FAQ about the limitation of "commits"

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, commitment-phase

I recently decided to commit to a few proposals. Well, I saw the "You can commit to 1 more site (?)." where the question mark is a link.

So I clicked it.

1. It didn't open the link in a new tab, so without pressing the back button, I lost all context that I was in. (bad UI practice)
2. It went to the (large) FAQ page. It should use `#` links so that it will go to the exact spot in the FAQ that I need to read.
3. I didn't see any info in the FAQ about this commit limit.

Comment: Same here. I expected to see more info about limit of commits in FAQ but did not find any. Even just referencing that you can only commit to n sites would be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All three issues are fixed now. Thanks!